# can't understand about () -> Call<WeatherData>

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

```
suspend fun  safeApiCall(
        apiCall: () -> Call<WeatherData>
    ): Resource<WeatherData> { 
         apiCall.enqueue()          //error Unresolved reference: enqueue
}
```

In the above code what it the meaning of `() -> Call<WeatherData>` and how it is different from `Call<WeatherData>`

Comment: Its a function as a parameter . and the `safeApiCall` function call  [Higher-Order Function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)

Comment: Thanks really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah the syntax is explained in the *[Function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types)* section of @ADM 's link.

Basically `apiCall`'s type is a function with no parameters (the `()`, like calling `someFunction()`) and it returns (`->`) a result with the type `Call<WeatherData>`. It's the equivalent of this:

```
fun apiCall(): Call<WeatherData>
```

except you can pass in any function that matches that signature (same parameter types, same return type). Which means you can pass in lambdas too

```
safeApiCall({ 
    doStuff()
    doMoreStuff()
    doThingThatReturnsAWeatherDataCall()
})
```

(when the lambda is the only parameter it can be moved out of the parentheses, I just wanted to make it clear you're passing it in as a parameter)

If you do have a function declared somewhere that matches the signature, you can pass a reference to that in instead

```
fun coolWeatherFunction(): Call<WeatherData>

safeApiCall(this::coolWeatherFunction)
```

(you can drop the `this`, just showing how you refer to a function on a particular instance or class)

It can be more readable sometimes

```
"1 2 3 4 5".split(' ').map(String::toDouble).forEach(::println)

1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```